# How can I get Latest Network Time Synchronization of quectel UC15 GPRS modem?

Tags: time, gsm, quectel

I send this command

```
"AT+QLTS"
```

and I receive this

answer:

```
+QLTS: ""OK
```

It did not get to me time. It registered to network properly and every other thing is ok.